# What security practices should I keep in mind before launching my website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I am about to launch a website(ruby on rails) related to tech knowledge sharing. It shall be hosted on AWS. I am specifically looking for a checklist to for "Best Security Practices". I have a few things in mind as follows.

1. Security headers
2. http redirection

Looking for more.

Comment: I voted to close this question because the topic is too broad to cover in a single answer here.  Questions that ask for a big list of responses are likely to attract many competing answers and incite voting wars and hostility.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really intrested in secure your website, take a look to OWASP 10. The most common attacks hacker to webserver & websites.
https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/

Answer (score 0):

Prevent external attacks and internal vulnerabilities

HTTP redirection and firewall to prevent some attacks, such as DDoS. Before it is completed and put online, someone can be invited to conduct penetration test to prevent potential threats

To be honest, if your website has a small audience, hackers will not pay attention to your site. At most, they will use it as an exercise and inform you of the vulnerability ha ha